# #name vs #name = "ngModel" in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control"
  required minlength="4" appForbiddenName="bob"
  [(ngModel)]="hero.name" **#name="ngModel"**>

<input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control"
  required minlength="4" appForbiddenName="bob"
  [(ngModel)]="hero.name" **#name**>
```

Is there any difference between the above two? Which is more correct way to use in Angular?

Answer (score 0):

Angular assigns a template variable a value based on where you declare the variable:

1. If you declare the variable on a component, the variable refers to the component instance.
2. If you declare the variable on a standard HTML tag, the variable refers to the element.

Since here you are assigning directive it is refer to `name="NgModel"`

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control"
      required minlength="4" appForbiddenName="bob"
      [(ngModel)]="hero.name" #name="ngModel"> 


<input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control"
  required minlength="4" appForbiddenName="bob"
  [(ngModel)]="hero.name" **#name**> //Here it refer to HTMLInputElement
```

**[For More Info](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables#syntax)**